# xcode 13.1 crash while project loading

Tags: ios, xcode, crash

I am trying to open a project made in Xcode 12 using Xcode 13.1 and I get crash. In Xcode 12 it opens without problems Log shown below. Can you help me ? Thank you.

P.S. I found that the problem is in Info.plist but could not localize it

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               Xcode [7074]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               13.1 (19466)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-19466000000000000~20 (13A1030d)
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       844664792
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-11-05 16:39:48.5109 +0200
OS Version:            macOS 12.0.1 (21A559)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        D316D717-0D90-660E-6F7F-7597A80EED19


Time Awake Since Boot: 25000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[__NSArrayM allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fef2821dc60
```

Comment: My problem is   Xcode 13.1  -> archive  -> Distribute App ->  loading"preparing summary" -> crash
its look  like the same type of problem.

Answer (score 2):

Problem did fix. While reading Info.plist Xcode 13 did crash on 'App Transport Security Settings' key parsing. I removed it from .plist & manually recreated 'App Transport Security Settings' key  hierarchy. Strange situation...

Comment: Thank you! Removing this line from plist file helped me.